# Display message in admin panel when file already exists

Tags: python, django, file, validation, model

My problem is how I can display a message in admin django (v 1.11) about the fact that the file that wants to put in the application exists.

I have already written the code, but it works only in the model, i.e. in the console you can see that `ValidationError` appears.

```
class ImageModel(BaseImageModel):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.has_all_mandatory_data = self._check_validity()
        if ImageModel.objects.filter(original_filename=self.file).exists():
            raise ValidationError('This image already exists.')
        super(ImageModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

How to show in admin `messages.INFO("File already exists")` instead of `ValidationError`?

Comment: May I ask, your problem is that you get an untemplated server error (ValidationError) on admin site and instead a nice message would be desirable?

Comment: @AlexanderStrakhov instead of ´ValidationError´ in terminal I would like to have ´messages.INFO´ i admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise ValidationError in save() method, then it should work (what you experience in console), but Django's admin cannot nicely handle such server response by default.

There is a workaround, Django's admin can nicely process ValidationError raised from one of the clean() methods of a model, see for 1.11: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects.

Thus, I would suggest to write your checking for existence logic in one of the clean() methods that Django provides us with, instead of writing it in save() method.

```
class ImageModel(BaseImageModel):
  desc = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)

  def clean(self):
    if ImageModel.objects.filter(original_filename=self.file).exists():
      raise ValidationError('This image already exists.')

  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      self.clean()
      super(ImageModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValidationError as e:
      non_field_errors = e.message_dict[NON_FIELD_ERRORS]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But please tell me where is here place for messages.INFO - we need `request` for that.

Comment: I do not think Django's admin will see messages.info by default. The method above should work by default though.